# Is Main Called Like Everything Else?

Tags: assembly, program-entry-point

If you were to look at standard assembly, is main called like normal functions, where afterwards a ret and sfp are put onto the stack, etc?  Had a huge objdump and I'm thinking this is the way it must be, because init and stuff happens before main, right?

Comment: standard assembly doesn't have a standard `main` does it?  Also, _which_ assembly are you asking about?  x86?

Comment: It depends on the implementation, but yes, typically in desktops `main` is invoked from init code, effectively as `ret = main(argc, argv);`, after all the initialization work is done. When `main` returns, the init code calls any `atexit()` callbacks, amongst other duties, then calls `exit(ret)`. In embedded platforms or simulators, this may not be the case - A simulator could simply start executing at `main()`, having set everything up already.

Comment: "Standard assembly?" There is no such thing. Assembly language is always processor instruction set architecture (ISA) specific.

Answer (score 3):

The actual entry point in your program is launched in an operating system specific way. I believe on windows you get a return address, so it is called. In linux for example, you can't use `ret` to end your program.

If you are speaking of the C `main` function, then you should be aware that it is not the entry point of the program, as that resides in the C library startup code which will indeed call your `main`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using 8086 assembler, the "main" is just a label with anyname, some people call it "start", or "begin". The compiler knows it is the starting point because at the end of the code you add "end main" or "end begin".

In the next examples the "main" or "begin" are the starting point, so the initialization for the data segment will never be executed because it is before the "main"/"begin" labels.

Because "main"/"begin" are not procedures, they don't requiere RET because they never where called with "call" instruction (there is no return address on stack). This is why it's necessary to end the program with ax=4c00h int 21h :

```
.stack 100h
.data
.code   
;INITIALIZE DATA SEGMENT.
  mov  ax,@data
  mov  ds,ax

main:           ;<======================
  xor  ax, ax  

;FINISH THE PROGRAM.
  mov  ax,4c00h
  int  21h         

end main           ;<======================
```

Or "begin" :

```
.stack 100h
.data
.code   
;INITIALIZE DATA SEGMENT.
  mov  ax,@data
  mov  ds,ax

begin:           ;<======================
  xor  ax, ax  

;FINISH THE PROGRAM.
  mov  ax,4c00h
  int  21h         

end begin           ;<======================
```

If the code doesn't include the "end main"/"end begin" directives, the starting point will be the "code" label (where the code segment starts).

Answer (score 0):

The behavior depends on the context, if your code is running on windows for instance, "main" is the entry point and is called by the os after the startup of the process and does have an address to return to when the program ends and it also reads EAX as exit code

Here is what it should look like when windows calls the entry point

```
/. 55             PUSH EBP
|. 8BEC           MOV EBP,ESP
|. 85C9           TEST ECX,ECX
|. 75 0C          JNZ SHORT KERNEL32.7672A53B
|. FF75 08        PUSH DWORD PTR SS:[EBP+8]
|. FFD2           CALL EDX <- Program entry point is called
|. 50             PUSH EAX
|. FF15 B4117976  CALL DWORD PTR DS:[<&ntdll.RtlExitUserTh>;  ntdll.RtlExitUserThread
|> F605 D002FE7F >TEST BYTE PTR DS:[7FFE02D0],10
|. 74 09          JE SHORT KERNEL32.7672A54D
|. E8 0F000000    CALL KERNEL32.7672A558
|. 85C0           TEST EAX,EAX
|. 78 02          JS SHORT KERNEL32.7672A54F
|> 33C0           XOR EAX,EAX
|> 5D             POP EBP
\. C2 0400        RETN 4
```